# No privileges to create databases

Tags: mysql

I just upgraded to mysql8

Have created a new user for phpmyadmin, but the user can not create new databases?

in phpmyadmin

```
No privileges to create databases
```

create user

```
CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## update

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `phpmyadmin`@`localhost`
GRANT APPLICATION_PASSWORD_ADMIN,AUDIT_ABORT_EXEMPT,AUDIT_ADMIN,AUTHENTICATION_POLICY_ADMIN,BACKUP_ADMIN,BINLOG_ADMIN,BINLOG_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,CLONE_ADMIN,CONNECTION_ADMIN,ENCRYPTION_KEY_ADMIN,FIREWALL_EXEMPT,FLUSH_OPTIMIZER_COSTS,FLUSH_STATUS,FLUSH_TABLES,FLUSH_USER_RESOURCES,GROUP_REPLICATION_ADMIN,GROUP_REPLICATION_STREAM,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ARCHIVE,INNODB_REDO_LOG_ENABLE,PASSWORDLESS_USER_ADMIN,PERSIST_RO_VARIABLES_ADMIN,REPLICATION_APPLIER,REPLICATION_SLAVE_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_ADMIN,RESOURCE_GROUP_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,SENSITIVE_VARIABLES_OBSERVER,SERVICE_CONNECTION_ADMIN,SESSION_VARIABLES_ADMIN,SET_USER_ID,SHOW_ROUTINE,SYSTEM_USER,SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN,TABLE_ENCRYPTION_ADMIN,TELEMETRY_LOG_ADMIN,XA_RECOVER_ADMIN ON *.* TO `phpmyadmin`@`localhost`
```

..

```
SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();

phpmyadmin@localhost
phpmyadmin@localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to phpmyadmin, and follow "Home" -> "Privileges" -> "Reload the Privileges".